# Wi-Fi drops since 10.10.3

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi, software-update

Since I did this OS update my Wi-Fi will not stay on all the time, it has trouble (**dropping**). Also, once I turn on my laptop it will search for Wi-Fi for a while and in turn sometime never find the saved Wi-Fi network. I am doing this all from my home and trusted network.

OS X Yosemite 10.10.3
MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Mid 2014)

Comment: You said you did "a number of things"  can you elaborate?  What did you do so we can narrow things down.

Comment: "Dropping" can have 2 reasons, low signal or crowded channel. How are those with you ?

Comment: → Jack : Is this problem fixed? How?

Answer (score 1):

Another thing to check is make sure IPV6 is configured as Link Local Only. To check go to System Preferences > Network > Wi-Fi > Advanced > TCP/IP. Also check for the Ethernet connection also. Also check the configuration of any Apple Routers and Apple Express units you may have for IPV6 configurations and change them to Link Local. I did this and my wifi is back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

This could be something as simple as your wifi router being that bit to far away, or being blocked by something such as too many walls or interfering devices for the startup problem.

For the wifi dropping problem, MacBooks now drop wifi while asleep and on battery power to conserve it. There doesn't appear to be a way to turn this off, I myself just put the device on screensaver and leave something such as a USB mouse to prevent it closing all the way if I need to keep the wifi. If it isn't happening when you're MacBook is sleeping then I can't help you there.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing the numerous walkthroughs you executed, there are a few things you can try (which you may have done already.)

The easiest is to remove all the Preferred Networks from System Preferences > Network > Wifi > Advanced button. Select each network and click the minus symbol. Then turn off wifi and restart it. Lastly, re-join the network you are having problems with.

You didn't mention whether you restarted the wireless router. This can sometimes help.

Lastly, are there any other wireless devices that you use (iPhone, other people's laptops, etc) which have the same problem?

Please let us know what troubleshooting steps you've taken already.

Wifi problems can be maddening. You're not alone.